# How to create CD from BIN file containing all sessions?

Tags: compact-disc, disk-image, cd-burning

I have a few multi session CDs where I have burnt data in multiple sessions on the same media. Using Power ISO software on Windows 7, I have created back up of those CDs in BIN file format, as BIN format supports multi session imaging.

This ensures that all sessions are imported into BIN. I can verify the same by opening the BIN later in Power ISO. It shows list of all sessions and asks for which session to import.

What I wonder is when I burn that BIN file on to a new blank CD-R Media, the resulting CD holds only the first session from the BIN. I am not too sure if I am missing any option in Power ISO software.

How  do I go about creating a CD from BIN that holds all sessions that are present in BIN file?

Any help would be great.

Comment: What's the point of replicating multi sessions *now*? Can't you gather all the relevant files and burn them at once?

Comment: Yes, I can do that eventually, but then doesn't it defeat the purpose of BIN file? If BIN file holds Folder-1 and Folder-2 but when CD Burner burns, it writes only Folder-1, then the purpose is defeated. That's what I wish to know if I am missing something or is this behavior by design of BIN file writing to CD?